# Emoji support for bookmarks bar on Chrome in Linux

Tags: linux, chrome, fonts, emoji, bookmarks

How can I get support for proper rendering of emojis in Chrome bookmarks bar? I'm using Ubuntu Linux or more specifically Xubuntu.

This is how it looks today:

[image]

I want them to be displayed as country flags, and with colors, like they appear in bookmark manager:

[image]

Comment: Which OS? Works fine on macOS.

Comment: Ahh, very good question :) I'ts Ubuntu Linux. I edited the question.

Comment: At a guess it looks like the font it's using for the UI doesn't have Unicode characters.. try a different font?

Comment: @bxm I can't figure out how to change the font though.

Comment: I'm not particularly au fait with XFCE but I'd imagine you'll want to be looking in its settings, assuming that Chrome is respecting the system UI font.

Comment: Hmm, yes actually, if i change the system font to "Noto color emoji", then the emojis show, but that font is a serif font, so then everything looks terrible on the whole desktop :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the answer at last, here: https://gist.github.com/arafathusayn/3d384adfbbdfe0b6a12868e9046e9a23
The trick was to configure Noto Color Emoji as a fallback font, so that the system will use that font when (and only when) a character is missing from the regular system font.
We don't want to use Noto Color Emoji as the system font, because it's not suited for GUI display.